# node, mongoose 'findOne' on one collection inside 'find' of another collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

Basically i have simple scenario, first i need to fetch whole collection, for example "cars" then iterate through that collection and execute 'findOne' on some another collection, for example "users" based on some condition from first collection.

So:

```
// requiring modules and mongoose.connect() part
...
CarModel.find(function(err, cars) {

    console.log("1");

    _.each(cars, function(car) {

        console.log("2");

        UserModel.findOne({username: car.owner}, function(err, user) {
            console.log("3");

            user.some_field++;
            user.save();
        });
    });
});
```

For example when cars collection has 2 documents(same car.owner) im expecting 2 increments for 'some_field' but i get only one.

```
// console.logs
1
2
2
3
3
```

I can guess that im doing something wrong here with flow of execution and asynchronous stuff, can someone explain me why this is not woriking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findOne` is async so the callbacks for both owners' `findOne` result can be queued up to run where `user.some_field` for both have the same initial value.  Each callback then runs and saves the new value as the initial value plus 1.

This is the classic case for why you want to use an update with the atomic [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) operator instead.

```
UserModel.findOneAndUpdate({username: car.owner}, {$inc: {some_field: 1}},
    function(err, numAffected) { ... }
);
```

Comment: @JohnyHK, thank you it is work.

Just one more side note, what about performance? Lets say that i have for example 100.000 documents in the cars collection or even million?

Comment: Glad it helped.  That's really a separate question so that's best posted separately.